# Overcome MD5-RSA Signature verification

Tags: hash, rsa, signature, md5

I asked this question already at the [Information Security SO](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/207245/attacking-a-update-mechanism-using-md5-and-rsa) site, but my research on how to overcome this problem ended always on the crypto site. That's why I will try to find some help here :)

I am currently working on a software challenge where you have to unlock several functions of a piece of software. The software is written in Java. One of them is the update mechanism of the firmware. What it does is to download a file from a webserver and make a few checks, before the update is performed. I need to find a way to overcome these checks in such a way, that I am able to update the firmware using my own created firmware update.

Here is how the update mechanism works:

1. The software downloads a file from the webserver. It is a zip file which should have the following structure:

   ```
   |Zip file content| SecurityTag: | Tag|
   ```

   - Zip file content: This is where I have to add a file, called `version.txt` which needs to contain a number `x > 1.0`. (The software reads that part as `ZipInputStream`.)
   - SecurityTag: This is a string, which has to be within this file! I cannot modify that one.
   - Tag: The Tag which is used during the check.
2. It takes the Zip file content, checks if the `version.txt` file is included and extracts the number from it.
3. It hashes the Zip file content using `hash = MD5(Zip file content)`
4. Takes the tag and decrypts it using RSA: `t = (tag)^e mod N`. I know `e=65537` and `N`.
5. It verifies if `hash == t` and `len(t) == len(hash)`.

Somehow, I have to pass this check but I am not sure how.

I had a look if I could make use of RSA's homomorphic property but I don't see how to do it efficiently :( I don't have any signature or any other information, besides the file structure and that it has to contain the `SecurityTag:` string and the public parameters `e = 65537` and `N`.

Is there any attack scenario which I am missing here? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: In general, `t = (tag)^e mod N` is an integer wider than the MD5 `hash` (which is 128-bit). Are all bytes of `t` involved in the check `hash == t`? If not, exactly which bytes are checked?

Comment: All bytes are involved. That means that `len(t) == len(hash)`.

Comment: That is weird. What is the size of N?

Comment: If `N` can't be factored, I fail to think of any on-topic solution for the [current statement](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/68727/3). I can imagine implementation goofs in the test "`hash == t` and `len(t) == len(hash)`", or that parsing the file (including decompressing the `ZipInputStream`, changing bytestream `| Tag|` to number `tag`..) allows a buffer overflow and some exploit, or cause an exception bypassing the check, or that `tag` is mishandled as a non-integer type, but none of this is crypto-related.

Comment: Please do not cross-post the same question to multiple sites. If it's not appropriate for one site, then ask a moderator to migrate it for you.

Comment: `N` is to large to be factored. I also checked for some coding errors or for vulnerabilities in some of the Java functions, but I haven't found anything. I had the hope that there is something with the crypto which I have overlooked.